# Open mail app with a specific mail in the inbox with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, email, io, applescript

I have the UID of a E-Mail message in the inbox.
Now I want to open Apple Mail (or alternatively Outlook) to present that mail to the user.
All examples I have found are how to start the standard Mail program to compose a new E-Mail.

Any Idea, hoe to solve that.
I tried with a Applescript but it does not work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      present_Email()
    }) {
      Text("Show E-Mail")
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
  }
}

func present_Email()
{
  let myAppleScript = """
    tell application "Mail"
    set myMessages to messages 1 through 1 of inbox
    repeat with aMesseage in myMessages
    open (contents of aMesseage)
    end repeat
    end tell
    """

  var error: NSDictionary?
  if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) {
    scriptObject.executeAndReturnError( &error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the path to the eml file?

Comment: @davidev unfortunately no, just the uid from a prior IMAP search.

Comment: I suggest you develop and debug the AppleScript code separately, in Script Editor. Once you’ve got it working there, then you can integrate it into your Swift code. (For non-trivial tasks, you’ll find [calling AS via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge] a lot easier than messing around with NSAppleScript.) Either way, you will need to catch and deal with any AS errors that may arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a quite easy Solution:
To open the Mail App with a given Message-ID you can simply open it via the message: URL Scheme.
No Need for AppleScript ;-).

```
Button(action: {
  NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "message:%3C...YOUR-MESSAGE_ID....%3E")!)
      }) {
        Text("Open E-Mail in Mail App")
      }
```

Comment: What is message ID here?

Comment: The UID of the e-mail. It's found in the e-mail header.